# printf function in c

Tags: c, printf

Does printf function in c calls argument by reference or by value?

Answer (score 12):

Everything in C is passed by value.

Even things that look like they're passed by reference (i.e., pointers to variables so that you can change the underlying variables) are in fact the *values* of the pointers being passed by value.

Comment: hi paxdiablo, let us consider we are passing the variable argument to a function in C++  then will they be passed by value or reference?

Comment: @Umesha, C++ has proper reference types, I believe. C doesn't have them. If you're talking about passing from C to C++, you're still limited by C's idioms unless you rely on extensions to the language. C itself (as in ISO C) does not cover inter-language stuff.

Answer (score 3):

There's no pass by reference in C, everything is by value or pointer-to-address by value

Answer (score 0):

call by reference is not applicable in c.
As in c we can't create alias of any variable,so eiher call by value or call by pointer mechanism is supported here..